# How to fix the selection of elements when mouseover

Tags: css, html

I need to create several `<span>` on multiple lines, and make them change color on mouse over.

Here is a quick example of my code:

```
<div class="example"><span class="text">BIG TEXT 1</span></div>
<div class="example"><span class="text">BIG TEXT 2</span></div>
<div class="example"><span class="text">BIG TEXT 3</span></div>
```

My problem occurs when I move the mouse over the text, where they overlap selection areas, but does not occur around the text.
To make you understand better, the selection changes from "TEXT 1" to "TEXT 2" while my mouse is in the lower half of the "TEXT 1",
but only above the written.

I hope I have given enough information about it.

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DWryan/3fbc049s/1/

Sorry for my english.
Tanks and regards.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but here it goes, if you change when `hover` is triggered, from the `.example` to `.text` does it get you where you want?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.example {
  display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.example:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <span class="text">BIG TEXT 1</span>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <span class="text">BIG TEXT 2</span>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <span class="text">BIG TEXT 3</span>
</div>
```

I changed the line-height to be something more standard and left off the unit of measure.  Usually the unit of measure is not included on line-height because it is derived from line-height * font-size.

/* Unitless: use this number multiplied by the element's font size */

Answer (score 0):

Move `font-size` from `.text` to `.example`.

Answer (score 0):

now `.example` block is smaller than its content but you don't see its border.

your problem is to extend `.example` block to fit its content.

you can solve the problem by 2 step:

1. add `overflow: hidden;` to `.example` style;
2. add `margin-top: 0.04em;` to `.text` style.